# Iframe cross-domain (not specific page) doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iframe

Using iframe for cross-domain request to not specif page in IE7 doesn't works. Following my code:

```
iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.name='iframe';
iframe.id = "iframe";
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iframe);
document.getElementById('iframe').src= "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=135+pilkington+avenue,+birmingham&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1";
```

How to solve it with pure javascript?

Comment: you really gave this name and id for your iframe?

Comment: Yes, I haven't a lot of imagination, but how to solve?

Comment: it's works for me. may be problem in other part of code?

Comment: just say iframe.src instead of getElements...

Comment: @IgorBenikov: name and ID do very different things on iframes...

Comment: @IgorBenikov it's doesn't work with IE7 and IE6.

Comment: @dandavis i tested it with iframe.src, it's doesn't work...

Comment: To be more precise, if you try my code with IE6/IE7, the browser proposes to you to download the intere page!